# click event not working when changing id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I'm starting with jquery, and have an issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8guzD/

```
$('#test.off').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
 });
$('#test.on').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    alert('ok');
});
```

the first part of the code goes well, the class is apply, but when I attach an event in this element with its new class it won't work.

Can someone explain me what is the problem exactly?

I tried with javascript, 
http://jsfiddle.net/R5NRz/

```
var element = document.getElementById('test');

element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.id ='test2';
    alert("ok");
}, false);

var element2 = document.getElementById('test2');

element2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("ok2");
}, false);
```

and it didn't really help me, having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    $(document).on("click",'#test.on',function(){

        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        alert('ok');
 });


$(document).on("click",'#test.off',function(){

        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        alert('ok passs');
 });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8guzD/3/)

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery example you are binding to DOM elements that exist at that time.  That is why you see the first fire but not the second.  It is not a match for your '#test.on' selector when the code is run.  What you want to do instead is use delegation:

```
$('#test').on('click',function() {
   var ele = $(this);
   if (ele.hasClass('on')) {
    ele.removeClass('on').addClass('off');
   } else {
    ele.removeClass('off').addClass('on');
   }
});
```

This assumes that you are doing more than just toggling classes.  If you want simply toggle classes then an easier solution is to pick one as the default and use the other as a flag.  For example, .on is on but without .on it's off.  Then you can just use toggle:

```
   $('#test').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('on');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test.on")
```

Doesn't bind to anything.  Try this:

```
$('#test').click(function() {   
  if($(this)).hasClass('off') $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');   
  else $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off'); 
});
```

You might consider using an 'active' class instead and just toggling that, instead of have two separate on/off classes.  Then you can write:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```